# Result is correct, but LinearProgramming spits out lpnn warning in RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, numerics, warning-messages

Sorry if this is a newbie question. I wrote a function to decide if a given vector is in the convex hull of another set of vectors using linear programming.

```
τ[dim_] := NMaximize[(dim - 2) Sin[s] + Sin[2 s], s][[1]]
τ[dim_, j_] := j NMaximize[(dim - 2 j) Sin[s] + j Sin[2 s], s][[1]]
BinaryCube[w_, bits_] := Table[(-1)^(BitAnd[w, 2^j]/2^j), {j, bits - 1, 0, -1}]
Proj[w_] := w - Sum[w[[i]], {i, 1, Dimensions[w][[1]]}]/Dimensions[w][[1]];
DB[dim_] := dim/2 Table[Proj[BinaryCube[w, dim]], {w, 1, 2^dim - 2}]
ConvexHull[M_, b_] := 
   If[Table[1, {j, 1, Dimensions[M][[2]]}] .
        LinearProgramming[Table[1, {j, 1, Dimensions[M][[2]]}], M, b] < 1,
     1, 0]
DBMatrix = Transpose[DB[3]]
RegionPlot[
  ConvexHull[DBMatrix, α {1, -1, 0}/Sqrt[2] + β {1, 1, -2}/Sqrt[6]] > 1/2, 
  {α, -3, 3}, {β, -3, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]
```

When I call the function with a fixed matrix (representing the vectors defining the vertices of the convex polytope) and vector that we are checking for membership in the convex region it runs fine but when I call it from `RegionPlot` it generates a warning.

> LinearProgramming::lpnn: Input data to linear programming algorithm {{1,1,1,1,1,1},{{1,1,2,-2,-1,-1},{1,-2,-1,1,2,-1},{-2,1,-1,1,-1,2}},{α/Sqrt[2]+β/Sqrt[6],-(α/Sqrt[2])+β/Sqrt[6],-Sqrt[(2/3)] β},{{}},{}} contains elements that are empty matrices, invalid vectors or matrices, or not real numbers.

Anyone know what is going on here? I am not sure where these empty vectors are coming from. For what it is worth it still generates what I know to be the correct plot in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be the empty lists in the message, they're there probably because `LinearProgamming` has internally treated

```
LinearProgamming[c, m, b]
```

as

```
LinearProgramming[c, m, b, {{}}, {}]
```

The real problem is probably the `α` and `β` therein. This seems to be another story of evaluation order, which can be fixed with the [frequently used `NumericQ` technique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/1871):

```
Clear@ConvexHull; 
ConvexHull[M_, b : {__?NumericQ}] := 
 If[Table[1, {j, 1, Dimensions[M][[2]]}] . 
    LinearProgramming[Table[1, {j, 1, Dimensions[M][[2]]}], M, b] < 1, 1, 0]
```

Tested in *v9.0.1* and *v12.2*.

Finally it's worth mentioning that the warning doesn't pop up in *v8.0.4* by default, and adding `Evaluated -> True` to `RegionPlot` in *v8.0.4* reproduces the warning. Nevertheless, `Evaluated -> False` cannot fix the problem in *v9.0.1* and *v12.2*. Bug or feature? I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.